# 8 image change on mouse hover and return to default when left

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an 8 img elements in my page -

```
<a href = "#"><img onmouseover="mousehover(this)" onmouseout="defaultImg(this)" src = "images/1_1.jpg" height="96" width="156" style="margin-right:12px;"/></a>
<a href = "#"><img onmouseover="mousehover(this)" onmouseout="defaultImg(this)" src = "images/2_1.jpg" height="96" width="156" style="margin-right:12px;"/></a>
```

On hover it should change from 1_1 to 1_2 till 1_8 and then 1_1 again. On mouse out it should show the default pic i.e 1_1. Like this i have 2_1, 3_1 till 8_1.

The javascript function for mousehover is -

```
function mousehover(x){
        for(var i=2; i<9; i++){
            x.src = x.src.replace('images/rotator/1_' + i + '.jpg');
        }

    }

    function defaultImg(x){
        x.src = x.src.replace("images/rotator/1_1.jpg");
    }
```

Somehow this mouse hover func does not work. And how do i get the defaultImg for all the images on mouse out. I am stuck here. Any ideas?

Comment: Dan you should post a fiddle

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: Doesnt toggle and on mouse out shows a no pic

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4pGrv/

Comment: I'm pretty sure replace is not the function you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the first number as parameter in the function calls.

```
<a href = "#"><img onmouseover="mousehover(this, 1)" onmouseout="defaultImg(this, 1)" src = "images/1_1.jpg" height="96" width="156" style="margin-right:12px;"/></a>
<a href = "#"><img onmouseover="mousehover(this, 2)" onmouseout="defaultImg(this, 2)" src = "images/2_1.jpg" height="96" width="156" style="margin-right:12px;"/></a>
```

And the JavaScript would be:

```
var interval;

function mousehover(x, y) {
  var i = 1;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    if (i > 8) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      i = 1;
    }
    x.src = 'images/rotator/' + y + '_' + i + '.jpg';
  }, 500);

}

function defaultImg(x, y) {
  clearInterval(interval);
  x.src = 'images/rotator/' + y + '_1.jpg';
}
```

For more performance, I would combine all images into one big sprite, and play with the background-position instead of loading a new image each time.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.Should work:

```
var timer;
var i=2;
function mousehover(x){
    x.src = 'images/rotator/1_' + i + '.jpg';
    i++;
    timer = setTimeout(function(){mousehover(x)},2000);
}

function defaultImg(x){
    i=2;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    x.src = "images/rotator/1_1.jpg";
}
```

Comment: works but doesnt for different images. For example i have 8 images and are named - 1_1, 1_2, 1_3 ---- 2_1, 2_2, 2_3 ---- 3_1, 3_2, 3_3  and so on.

Comment: how can i store the original image name so that once i mouseout then i can put in that name? For example in your solution if i am on image 2_1 then on mouse out it should be 2_1

Answer (score 0):

Something in these lines should work:

```
var element = document.querySelector("#switch");

element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
   this.src = "http://placehold.it/400x300";
});

element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
   this.src = "http://placehold.it/200x300";
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6LyV/)

Comment: But this is just for one img. I have to show 8 different pics at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
//TIP: Insert listeners with javascript, NOT html

x.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {

    var count = 1,
        that = this,
        timer;

    timer = setInterval(function () {

        if (count < 8) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }

        that.src = 'images/rotator/1_' + count + '.jpg';
    }, 500);

    function onMouseOut() {
        that.src = 'images/rotator/1_1.jpg';
        that.removeEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut)
    }

    this.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);
});
```